# How to select rows in pandas dataframe based on values in other columns and How to select one row for each distinct value in particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie to pandas and I'm having problems while selecting values from a DF based on values in other columns.
Following is my dataframe:

```
     C1     C2      C3              C4 
0    1234   1002    Operational     ABC
1    5678   2001    Closed          ABC
2    7896   1002    Operational     DEF
3    4321   4005    Closed          CDE
4    7781   4005    Operational     ABC
```

Q1. I want to select duplicate values in C2 whose C3 value is 'Operational'.
Output dataframe should be

```
C1      C2      C3              C4 
1234    1002    Operational     ABC
7896    1002    Operational     ABC
```

I've tried df[(df.duplicated(['C2'], keep=False)) & df['C3'] == 'Operational'] but it is selecting rows with index 0,2,4. But I want only rows with index 0 and 2 as a output.

Q2. How to select one row for each distinct value in C4.
Output dataframe should be

```
    C1      C2      C3              C4  
    7896    1002    Operational     DEF
    4321    4005    Closed          CDE
    7781    4005    Operational     ABC
```

Can I get any suggestions for these two custom selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first solution is easier filtered twice - first only `Operational` and then `duplicates`:

```
df1 = df[df['C3'] == 'Operational'] 
df1 = df1[df1.duplicated(['C2'], keep=False)]
print (df1)
     C1    C2           C3   C4
0  1234  1002  Operational  ABC
2  7896  1002  Operational  DEF
```

What is same, but worse readable:

```
m1 = df['C3'] == 'Operational'
df1 = df[df[m1].duplicated(['C2'], keep=False) & m1]
print (df1)
     C1    C2           C3   C4
0  1234  1002  Operational  ABC
2  7896  1002  Operational  DEF
```

And for second question use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `keep='last'` for get last value of duplicates in `C4`:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('C4', keep='last')
print (df2)
     C1    C2           C3   C4
2  7896  1002  Operational  DEF
3  4321  4005       Closed  CDE
4  7781  4005  Operational  ABC
```

Or if is necesary remove consecutive dupes only:

```
mask = df['C4'].ne(df['C4'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
     C1    C2           C3   C4
2  7896  1002  Operational  DEF
3  4321  4005       Closed  CDE
4  7781  4005  Operational  ABC
```